# SSIS: convert generated string into datetime: DT_WSTR to DT_DBDATE

Tags: date, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have this expression `(DT_WSTR, 10)(year(getutcdate())-2)+"-01-01"` that results in the string `2018-01-01`.
NOw I want that string converted to a datetype but it complains that I cannot convert from DT_WSTR to DT_DBDATE (or any other datetype)

Curiously, it keeps complaining about WSTR if I try to use (DT_STR, 10,1252)(year(getutcdate())-2)+"-01-01"

How do I convert that generated string into a datetype DATE?

The ultimate goals is to get the 1st of january 2 years back at 12:00:00 AM
Since I am working on systems with different datesettings I prefer to avoid strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)DATEADD("M",-MONTH(GETDATE())+1,DATEADD("D",-DAY(GETDATE())+1,DATEADD("YEAR",-2,GETUTCDATE())))
```